# libuv and uv_buf_init: who should free what?

Tags: c, libuv

Consider the official [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html) for *libuv* (section *miscellaneous utilities*).
This is the declaration of `uv_buf_init`:

```
uv_buf_t uv_buf_init(char* base, unsigned int len)
```

The documentation states that (emphasis mine):

> Constructor for uv_buf_t.
>
> Due to platform differences the user cannot rely on the ordering of the base and len members of the uv_buf_t struct. **The user is responsible for freeing base after the uv_buf_t is done**. Return struct passed by value.

It seems to me that `base` can be freed immediately after a call to `uv_buf_init`.

On the other side, a `uv_buf_t` structure [is documented](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html#c.uv_buf_t) as composed by two fields: `base`, that has type `char *`, and `len`, that has type `size_t`.

What is not clear to me is:

- Are data copied over into the buffer? (Well, I guess the answer is no, for it would be a great penalty in terms of performance).
- Should I free the data once a call to `uv_try_write` or the other `*_write` functions is done instead? That is, once the data have been actually consumed indeed.

Comment: You should use valgrind to check, or also read the source code if the documentation is not sufficient. Also, the platform differences in where it is actually stored seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: @self Read the source and yes: the documentation is not sufficient (it's terrible indeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data are not copied over to the `uv_buf_t`, `uv_buf_t.base` refers to the same array of characters you used to create it.
Because of that, you have no performance penalties, but also you cannot drop the data immediately after the call to `uv_buf_init`.
Instead, you can free them once you have *used* the buffer, that is (as an example) when you have submitted it to `uv_write` or `uv_try_write`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the `struct`, but worry about what it points to.

If the function you pass the `uv_buf_t` to is used in an asynchronous way the memory that `uv_buf_t.base` points to must *not* be freed until the callback is called.

Even cancelling in progress requests like `uv_write_t` (by calling close on the handle) does not prevent the callbacks from getting called, so it's safe to do the cleanup there.